# SQL IN operator is not working with multiple value of scalar variable in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have facing a problem that SQL `IN` operator did not work with multiple value of scalar variables in C#, but query works in SQL Server 2012.

This is working:

```
SELECT WorkStatus  
FROM viewWorkRequest 
WHERE WorkStatus IN ('Open', 'Closed')
```

But it's not working in C#

```
string All = "'Open','Closed'";
string sql = "SELECT WorkStatus FROM viewWorkRequest WHERE WorkStatus IN (@WorkStatus)"

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkStatus", All);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the sql is obvious different.

Comment: You cannot pass multiple values via a single parameter. The code you're executing is equivalent to this: `WorkStatus IN('''Open'',''Closed''')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you think that the fact that the first SQL works would have any bearing on the second SQL, which doesn't contain an `IN` clause?

Each parameter can only contain a single value and each value in an `IN` clause is distinct, so you cannot pass multiple values for an `IN` clause with a single parameter. If you don't know how many values you will have then you have to build your SQL in such a way as to allow for a variable number of parameters, e.g.

```vb
var values = new[] {"Open", "Closed"};
var sql = $"SELECT * FROM viewWorkRequest WHERE WorkStatus IN ({string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length).Select(n => "@WorkStatus" + n))})";
var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@WorkStatus" + i, SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = values[i];
}
```

Comment: I want to also show the all open and all closed data individually, Please guide me how can I do it with your code?

Comment: @TanvirAhmedHowlader, that's not the question I was answering because that's not the question you asked. If you have a different question then please post it separately, providing all and only the information relevant to that. It sounds like you need to make multiple queries though, which is completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: I did it. Just add a extra variable with condition  Enumerable.Range(0, rbnAllWorkRequest.Checked ? values.Length : range). its working properly.